# Rect DevTools Error in React Native: Could not inspect element with id

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-devtools

Hi I am trying to debug my expo react native app with react devtools. The problem is that I could not inspect any component in my app as it shows this error:

[image]

I am using ios emulator. Hope you guys could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it use React Native Debugger instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this step to solve this issue:

#1 Check you have added **react-devtools** inside the package.json project if not then add compatible version:

```
npm i react-devtools | yarn i react-devtools
```

#2 You also check if you have install react-devtools globally with similar version with package.json project.